# how to put out a hint after 4 tries?

Tags: c++

I am creating a game in C++ called GUESS OR DIE, which is kinda similar to HANGMAN. I want to put an if statement wherein like for example, if the word was PROGRAMMING, then it will give a Hint on case 4 or before the object drops on the head of the person. I have tried putting an if statement on case 4 but it just randomizes the hints.

The codes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

string randWord();
void game();
void gotoxy(int x, int y);
int Letter(char x, string &word);
int Obj(int x);

/***********************************************************************
        Main Function
/***********************************************************************/

int main()
{
    // This is the Menu Section

    Menu:

    system("COLOR 1F");
    system("cls");
    cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t    \xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc       \n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t    \xdb                                 \xdb \n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t    \xdb           GUESS OR DIE          \xdb \n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t    \xdb                                 \xdb \n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t    \xdb           1. Start              \xdb \n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t    \xdb           2. Tutorial           \xdb \n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t    \xdb           3. Exit               \xdb \n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t    \xdb                                 \xdb \n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t    \xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf       \n\n";

    int choice;
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t    > "; cin >> choice;

    // If choice == 1, then go to the game itself.

    if(choice == 1)
    {
        system("cls");
        game();
        string rWord = randWord();
        string reserveString = rWord;
        int StickMan = 0, yesno;
        char letter;
        cout << "\n\n\n "; for(int i = 0; i < rWord.length(); i++) cout << " _ ";
        cout << "\n\n Enter your letter: ";
        while(1)
        {
            gotoxy(21, 15);
            cin >> letter;
            switch(Letter(letter, rWord))
            {
                case 0:
                    switch(Obj(++StickMan))
                    {
                        case 0:
                            gotoxy(9, 4);
                            cout << ' ';
                            gotoxy(9, 5);
                            cout << ' ';
                            gotoxy(9, 6);
                            cout << ' ';
                            gotoxy(9, 7);
                            cout << ' ';
                            gotoxy(9, 8);
                            cout << 'X';
                            gotoxy(1, 15);
                            cout << "   GAME OVER. Your word was --> " << reserveString << endl;
                            gotoxy(1, 17);
                            cout << "                                                                                                                          ";

                            int counter = 10; //amount of seconds
                            Sleep(1500);

                            system("cls");
                            cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
                            cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t   " << "\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc" << endl;
                            cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t   " << "\xdb                \xdb" << endl;
                            cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t   " << "\xdb                \xdb" << endl;
                            cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t   " << "\xdb                \xdb" << endl;
                            cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t   " << "\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf";

                            do
                            {
                                gotoxy(54, 14);
                                cout << "Continue? " << setw(2) << setfill(' ') << counter << endl;
                                Sleep(1000);
                                counter--;
                            }while (counter >= 1);

                            cout << "\n" << endl;

                            return 0;
                    }
                    break;

                case 1:
                    gotoxy(9, 4);
                    cout << ' ';
                    gotoxy(9, 5);
                    cout << ' ';
                    gotoxy(9, 6);
                    cout << ' ';
                    gotoxy(9, 7);
                    cout << ' ';
                    gotoxy(4, 14);
                    cout << "You Won!!\n";
                    gotoxy(1, 17);
                    cout << "                                                                                                                          ";
                    return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    // If choice == 2, then go to the TUTORIAL page.

    if(choice == 2)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t    \xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc \n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t    \xdb                                                  \xdb \n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t    \xdb                     TUTORIAL                     \xdb \n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t    \xdb                                                  \xdb \n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t    \xdb    - Once you have chosen Start, input           \xdb \n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t    \xdb      letters one by one and try to solve the     \xdb \n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t    \xdb      hidden word. After 4 tries, a  hint         \xdb \n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t    \xdb      will show up and you can still guess        \xdb \n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t    \xdb      the word but only 1 try left. If you        \xdb \n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t    \xdb      still don't get it, an object will          \xdb \n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t    \xdb      fall and crash on your head and you         \xdb \n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t    \xdb      will die.                                   \xdb \n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t    \xdb                                                  \xdb \n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t    \xdb                     A. Back                      \xdb \n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t    \xdb                                                  \xdb \n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t    \xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf\xdf \n\n";

        char option;
        cout << "\t\t\t\t    > ";
        cin >> option;

        // If option == 'A' || 'a', then the program goes to back the menu section.

        if(option == 'A' || 'a')
        {
            goto Menu;
        }

    }

    // If choice == 3, a message will be outputted and then the program will end.

    if(choice == 3)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\xB2                        \xB2\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\xB2 Thank You! Come Again! \xB2\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\xB2                        \xB2\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\n";
    }

    return 0;
}

/***********************************************************************
        Drawing the table on the screen
/***********************************************************************/

void game()
{
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "   GUESS OR DIE " << endl;
    cout << "                " << endl;
    cout << "   \xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc\xdc      " << endl;
    cout << "   \xdb            " << endl;
    cout << "   \xdb            " << endl;
    cout << "   \xdb            " << endl;
    cout << "   \xdb            " << endl;
    cout << "   \xdb     O      " << endl; // Head
    cout << "   \xdb    /|\\    " << endl; // Arms & Body
    cout << "   \xdb    / \\    "; // Legs
}

/***********************************************************************
        generating a random word for us to guess
/***********************************************************************/

string randWord()
{
    string words[5] = {"PROGRAMMING", "COMPUTER", "CODER", "DEBUGGING", "COMPILE"};

    srand(time(0));
    return words[rand() % 5];
}

/***********************************************************************
        Writing the letters on the screen
/***********************************************************************/

int number = 0;
int Letter(char x, string &word)
{
    bool foundLetter = false;
    x = toupper(x);
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        if (x == word[i])
        {
            gotoxy(2 + i * 3, 13);
                cout << x;
            foundLetter = true;
            number++;
            word[i] = '0';
        }
    }
    if(!foundLetter)
        return 0;
    else if(number == word.length())
        return 1;
    return 2;
}

/***********************************************************************
        Drawing the stickman on the screen / Falling Ball
/***********************************************************************/

int Obj(int x)
{
    string randWord();
    string rWord = randWord();
    string reserveString = rWord;

    switch(x)
    {
        case 1:
            gotoxy(9, 4);
            cout << '\x1f';
            break;
        case 2:
            gotoxy(9, 4);
            cout << ' ';
            gotoxy(9, 5);
            cout << '\x1f';
            break;
        case 3:
            gotoxy(9, 4);
            cout << ' ';
            gotoxy(9, 5);
            cout << ' ';
            gotoxy(9, 6);
            cout << '\x1f';
            break;
        case 4:
            gotoxy(9, 4);
            cout << ' ';
            gotoxy(9, 5);
            cout << ' ';
            gotoxy(9, 6);
            cout << ' ';
            gotoxy(9, 7);
            cout << '\x1f';

            if(reserveString == "PROGRAMMING")
            {
                gotoxy(1, 17);
                cout << "Hint: " << "It is the process of creating a set of instructions that tell a computer how to perform a task.";
            }
            if(reserveString == "COMPUTER")
            {
                gotoxy(1, 17);
                cout << "Hint: " << "It is a programmable device for processing, storing, and displaying information.";
            }
            if(reserveString == "CODER")
            {
                gotoxy(1, 17);
                cout << "Hint: " << "It is a person who writes code for computer programs.";
            }
            if(reserveString == "DEBUGGING")
            {
                gotoxy(1, 17);
                cout << "Hint: " << "It is the process of finding and resolving bugs within computer programs, software, or systems.";
            }
            if(reserveString == "COMPILE")
            {
                gotoxy(1, 17);
                cout << "Hint: " << "It converts (a program) into a machine-code or lower-level form in which the program can be executed.";
            }

            break;
        case 5:
            return 0;
    }
}

/***********************************************************************
        Displacing the cursor on the screen
/***********************************************************************/

void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    COORD coord;
    coord.X = x;
    coord.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}
```

[Example of Output: (Random Hints, sometimes the word you have to guess matches with the hint, sometimes it doesn't)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TrUJ.png)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it randomizes the hints". I don't see anything that keeps track of the number of guesses; you'd need that, and then before/after the *nth* guess, print something.

Comment: Sorry, I have forgotten to put the codes of me trying to put if statements in case 4. I have edited my post now.

Comment: Please make a [mre] which focuses only on the guessing, the counting and the hinting. Most decorative output should be dropped.

Comment: It's difficult to see where in the code this problem is being addressed; there's a lot of "extra" here that may be important for the final program, but hides implementation problems without extra digging. `Obj` also doesn't appear to return anything most of the time, which seems like a Bad Idea.

Comment: Yunnosch
- The counting of guesses depends on the input. The int obj is the one that prints the falling object. Sorry, I'm just a beginner at C++.

Comment: Can anyone please help me, I still don't know what to do here :(